# why is RigidbodyAddForce not moving my Capsule?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

My Code

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Grounded()) rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Grounded()) rb.AddForce(-transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Grounded()) rb.AddForce(transform.right * speed * 0.75f * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Grounded()) rb.AddForce(-transform.right * speed * 0.75f * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

In the Update ffunction intended to move the player is doing nothing
also the grounded function is currently set to return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet otherwise I would have asked more questions but here are some things I'd try to help debug:

1. Is Grounded() returning true? Try putting a print statement in your FixedUpdate that prints Grounded() to ensure that it's returning true.
2. Is your speed high enough? Try setting it to a number like 10,000. It's possible, if your objects are a really large scale for some reason, that it's moving but you can't tell because it's such slight movement.
3. Make sure rb is calling a valid rigidbody. With just this code I can't ensure that the rigidbody is properly set.
4. Try removing elements of your code one by one to find what's causing the issue. Your syntax appears to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out, I just wasn't giving it enough force

Answer (score 0):

It should work, make sure the speed variable is not 0.

Also:

- You should do everything Rigidbody related in FixedUpdate(), but keep your inputs in Update().

> Fixed Update is called exactly before every physics update, so you do
> not have to worry about timing and inconsistencies. Update, on the
> other hand, is called based on framerate and not the speed of physics
> updates. [More info on FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Then you would have to replace `Time.deltaTime` by `Time.fixedDeltaTime`

- Did you consider using axis instead of keycode-based inputs?